# Testing a RestTemplate in same project as RestController or different?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a RestController in a microservice, do I test RestTemplate in the same project or against it from a different project?

Comment: Please post what you have or what you are trying to do

Comment: This is definitely a broad question and would be helpful if you provide a little more information. For me, .net apps always get tested in a separate project, in js, the spec file is next to th class, etc. I’d hunt around for spring mvc GitHub projects, or supply folks with a little more information in what you are doing, tech, etc.

Comment: I am sorry for how broad the question is, I haven't written any code for testing my Rest Controller yet and have searched the whole of yesterday (maybe should of searched harder) for a answer but the question was answered. I was making sure it wasn't specific to one side(server side or client side) of the project. Thanks for helping. @AndyDangerGagne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done either way.
I would create unit test cases and integration test cases within the same project. With unit and integration testing, I would test the functionality and ensure my service is connecting to all dependent resources.

If I am writing a smoke test suite or an end to end test suite which tests the service as invoked by an external client, then I would create test case in a different project to ensure invoking the service works without any dependency to the original project.

Comment: Thank you for the information, it answered my question.